# WordPress 3 Visual Editor - How to add spaces?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using WordPress 3.0.1 and the Twenty-ten theme. How can I add spaces to this section of text in the Visual Editor?

HTML Editor Mode looks like this:

```
<p style="text-align: left; padding-left: 30px;">-        With each visit each client will be provided with a full detailed<br />
 report and invoice<br />
 -        Each pool and spa service and maintenance is covered with  an <br />
 activity check list<br />
 -        Each personnel has the experience required<br />
 -        Our organization can supply and install all major brands and <br />
 models<br />
 -        All workmanship is guaranteed<br />
 -        All products supplied come with manufacture warranties</p>
```

But I am in actual fact modifying this block of text within the Visual Editor using manual entry with the hyphens and text but unfortunately when I press shift-enter between the words "detailed" and "report"  first line, the "return" word does not sit right under the word "With" even when I add spaces before the "return" word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to make a list correct? Instead of trying to space it out yourself, instead make this an unordered list. Then you can use CSS to make the bullets in to hyphens and align each entry the way you require. Sample list -

- With each visit each client will be provided with a full detailed report and invoice
- Each pool and spa service and maintenance is covered with  an activity check list
- Each personnel has the experience required
- Our organization can supply and install all major brands and models
- All workmanship is guaranteed
- All products supplied come with manufacture warranties

Comment: BTW - the reason your spaces are not showing up is that HTML ignores multiple spaces. In order for HTML to insert more than one space you need to use '&nbsp;'

Comment: Hi Brent, thanks for your help but some reason, it looks like my indent button in my visual editor is not indenting unordered lists. But will indent non unordered list items and really don't know why?

Comment: I am assuming that you mean the visual editor within WP. Chances are that the stylesheet being used by the editor has padding/margin removed from unordered lists for some reason. However, you should be able to control that using the stylesheet for your theme. Give your list an ID then use margin/padding (depends on how you are placing your list) to indent it. You will also need to make sure that the list-style-type is set to "outside" so that any content that wraps to the next line lines up with the text above it instead of the bullet.